# Choosing a Class Dynamically in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class

I have a line of code like this:

```
var myObj:[SomeClass] = new [SomeClass]();
```

I want to choose which class this object will belong to randomly at runtime. Is there a way to do this in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how well this would fly in AS3, but in JS, I'd use

```
var classes = [foo, bar, baz];
var myObj = new_(classes[random() % 3])();
```

maybe it'd work in AS3 too?

`new_` is part of Zeta (http://codex.sigpipe.cz/zeta/docs/reference.rest#new-cls), random() is pulled from thin air.

Comment: That actually almost works! All I had to do was remove the underscore after 'new'. Thanks!

Comment: Add `Math.` in front of that thing you pulled from thin air if you want it working.

Comment: Math.random returns floats from the range [0, 1).  you'd want sth like this:

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct way to do this. But you can try this thing.

```
var funcArray:Array = new Array();

public function getObjClass1():Class1 {
  return new Class1();
}
...
...
public function getObjClassN():ClassN {
  return new ClassN();
}
//add all functions to funcArray array
public function addFunctions():void {
  funcArray.push(getObjClass1);
  ...
  funcArray.push(getObjClassN);
}

public function getRandomObject():* {
  return funcArray\[Math.floor(Math.Random() * funcArray.length)\]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes Object Oriented Programming:

Declare your variable's type as a common super class's type (or an interface) and extend (or implement) all the possible classes from that super class (or interface).

```
public class MyType
{
}
public class Type1 extends MyType
{
}
public class Type2 extends MyType
{
}
public class Type3 extends MyType
{
}

var something:MyType;
//Now you can do
something = new Type1();
something = new Type2();
something = new Type3();
```

Here is a sample using interfaces:

```
public interface MyType
{
}
public class Type1 implements MyType
{
}
public class Type2 implements MyType
{
}
public class Type3 implements MyType
{
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm planning to do...but I didn't want to write a long switch/if statement that went like "if (randomnumber == 1) { do this } else if....". Sorry that part wasn't clear. But yeah, using OO this is absolutely the approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like:

```
var classes:Array = [Class1, Class2, Class3];
var obj:Obj = new classes[0];
```

Each class will probably have to implement a shared interface to make it useful. So it would look something like:

```
var classes:Array = [Class1, Class2, Class3];
var obj:IInterface = (new classes[0]) as IInterface;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following if you have several classes: Class1, Class2, Class3 who all extend AbstractItem

```
var itemClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("com.packagename.Class" + Math.floor(Math.random()*3 +1)) as Class;
var item:AbstractItem = new itemClass();
```

Comment: if you do this you need to make sure the classes are used somewhere else in your code, if you don't they wont get compiled in.

Comment: true, you can easily fix this by making corresponding variables to be sure the classes get compiled: 
var item:Class1;
var item:Class2;
var item:Class3;

Answer (score 0):

This is what [just somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209605/just-somebody)'s answer would look like in proper AS3 syntax.

```
var classes:Array = [Foo, Bar, Baz];
var myObj:YourSuperclass = new classes[int(Math.random() * classes.length)];
```

If the classes do not have a common superclass you can keep myObj untyped.